# Web.config run PHP file without an extension

Tags: php, apache, web-config

I have a PHP script that is simply called 'reviews' located in /products/ 
so I want when the user goes to www.mydomain.com/products/reviews it executes the PHP script. Is there a way to set this up in the Web.config file?

At the moment it simply displays the entire contents of the file

Comment: web.config? Is this Apache or IIS?

Comment: Does your main script parse the PHP or does it also display the file contents?

Comment: It's apache, web.config is the same as IIS tho right?

Comment: Parse the script, so that `<?php echo "Hello"; ?>` outputs `Hello`

Comment: Why do you think apache and IIS config files are even similar?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your file will need a .php extension so that it can be identified as a PHP script an executed.
As far as not displaying the extension goes, you can accomplish this by editing the apache2.conf file (at least on my system) or adding to a .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*[^.]+)$ /$1.php [L]
```

Now if you request /reviews , the server will check if reviews.php exists and execute that. The URL will still display without the extension.

Comment: I put a .htaccess file in /products/ and added .php, but it simply gives me 404 not found

Comment: Your .htaccess file needs to be in the web root, also it may be disabled. Check this link I just found on how to enable it: http://www.lifeburner.com/2009/07/14/how-to-enable-htaccess-in-apache2-on-a-ubuntu-server/ , can you confirm what OS your using ?

Comment: The OS is linux. .htaccess is enabled as I have one that pw protects a dir

Comment: Oh.. I had to put in the root dir :O missed that bit :P thanks so much :D:D